# MS SQL impersonates Administrator as "guest"

Tags: sql-server, permissions, roles

I have added `BUILTIN\Administrators` to the `sysadmin` role. However, a member of this group cannot access any database (other than master), although I specifically added them to `db_owner` for two databases. When they execute `SELECT ORIGINAL_LOGIN( )`, it returns "guest". When they execute `SELECT IS_MEMBER ('BUILTIN\Administrators')` it returns 1.

Only after I added `BUILTIN\Users` to the same role, they were able to work with databases.

How do I give all members of `BUILTIN\Administrators` sysadmin rights?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Builtin\Administrators doesn't permit access](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/156264/5203)

Comment: Seems like you should *really* be using AD groups.

Comment: >>>When they execute SELECT ORIGINAL_LOGIN( ), it returns "guest"<<< guest cannot be a login, it's a user, so  ORIGINAL_LOGIN( ) returns something else